# Add Area Option for Mvc application missing in VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an vs 2015, i am working on mvc application but when i tried to **add area  i cann't see add area option** any where in those option, but i could able to add those in 2012 version. And also in case of adding controller to the project **i can't add normal MVc controller** to my project it's giving only option for adding Web api controller and and its types, how should i make this work ? sholud i install some scaffolder templates or what ? can i get the solution for this issue ?? , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For **VS 2019**

1. Press right click on ur project

[2. Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6uO.png)

[3. New Scaffolded Item...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNMqu.png)

[4. MVC 5 Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mihTe.png)

Comment: consider uploading your images directly in StackOverflow so your answer won't lose information in case the links to the external images go dead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the problem that it's my project issue. adn becuase it was a mvc4 project and i am trying to run in vs 2015, it couldn't able to recongnize as right version.

and Updating my project mvc version **solved the problem**

Ref 1.https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Ref 2.http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/04/how-to-fix-systemmethodaccessexception.html